# Tensorflow: Incompatible shapes: [32,12] vs. [32,4]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I've got myself into a bit of trouble. I've got 4 features, and I want to predict each one of them at the same time. My lookback is 12 and I want to predict 12 timesteps ahead. Is it possible to predict all the 4 targets in parallel?

I have to following piece of code. Shape on train_df is (40000, 4) and val_df is (8000, 4).

```
win_length=12
batch=32
n_features=4

train_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(train_df, train_df, length=win_length, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=batch)
val_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(val_df, val_df, length=win_length, sampling_rate=1, batch_size=batch)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='tanh', input_shape=(win_length, n_features), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

model.fit_generator(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator)
```

I get the following error from the fit_generator-function, and I can't seem to figure out how so. Any ideas?

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32,12] vs. [32,4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand how `TimeseriesGenerator` works, but it seems like you want to have two same sequences for data and target, hence the `mse`. I've checked myself and `TimeseriesGenerator` doesn't produce two same sequences (data with shape (32, 12, 4) and targets with shape (32, 4)). My best bet right now is to implement the generator manually. Also I think `model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))` should be changed to `model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4)))`

Comment: Yea, the reason I want to use the same sequences for data and target is that I want to forecast all the features in the dataset, so the features essentially become my targets as well. The reason Dense(1) should be Dense(4) is that I want to forecast 4 targets, right?

Comment: Yeah, since the output shape will be [batch_size, 12, 4], which I guess is similar to your ideal output.

Comment: Exactly, because I want to forecast the each feature 12 timesteps ahead. [32, 12, 4] does mean 32 batches with 12 timesteps (rows) for alle the 4 features, right?

Comment: Yep, exactly that.